# Undefined index when trying to echo array element

Tags: php, arrays, undefined-index

I have what will probably turn out to be  major noob error.  I have an array under $_POST that displays the following when I var_dump it:

> array(4) { ["user"]=> array(2) { ["username"]=> string(9) "webmaster" ["email"]=> string(24) "webmaster@go-upsmart.com" } ["_wpnonce_add-user"]=> string(10) "d7ba190414" ["_wp_http_referer"]=> string(30) "/wp-admin/network/user-new.php" ["add-user"]=> string(8) "Add User" }

The part that I'm interested in is the `["username"]=> string(9) "webmaster"`

But when I try to get it using a $_POST['username'], I get a `Undefined index: username`

It's gotta be right under my nose, could someone help me connect the dots?

Many thanks in advance for any attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The username element you are trying to access is itself a member of an array called "user"
You need to use  $_POST['user']['username']